Brillouin zone(s) the Fermi surface lies within
I'm trying to understand how you can calculate which Brillouin zone(s) the fermi surface lies within. The way that seems reasonable for me is to:

1: Calculate the fermi radius.
2:Look in the "unique" directions of the reciprocal lattice and calculate the vectors in
those directions to the Brillouin edge, e.g. for fcc lattice look in the directions
$\Gamma X$, $\Gamma L$ and $\Gamma W$.
3: Compare the size of the fermi radius with the size of the vectors to the Brillouin edge ( $\Gamma X$, $\Gamma L$ and $\Gamma W$).
4: If one of the vectors is less than the fermi radius, then add the reciprocal lattice
vector $\textbf{G}_{hkl}$ in that direction and start from 3 again.

I thought that you could see in which Brillouin zone(s) the fermi surface lies within by checking these directions and squeeze the fermi radius in by (eventually) adding the reciprocal lattice vector $\textbf{G}_{hkl}$ to it. But it does not seem to work, can someone help me out in where I think wrong?
